# How to calculate photon absorbtion in gas

Tags: photons, absorption, gas

Imagine 1 cubic centimeter of ozone at atmosferic pressure,UV laser beam with 255 nm wavelenght,1 Watt power and square beam shape strikes the ozone cube,how much energy gets absorbed into ozone?

Does mean free path of photon in ozone equals distance where 50% of energy is absorbed? For example,if mean free path is 1 mm,then if I make "blanket" 1 mm thick,then it will absorb half the incoming photons?

Comment: "Does mean free path of photon in ozone equals distance where 50% of energy is absorbed?" - You have to distinguish between attenuation by scattering and attenuation by absorption. I believe that the mean free path of a photon is related to attenuation due to either scattering or absorption and not just due to absorption alone.  Also, I don't think that the total attenuation for a distance equal to the mean free path is 0.5 . I think that it's 1/e where e is Euler's (or equivalently Napier's ?) constant.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what does the "absorbtion cross section cm2" mean?

Answer (score 1):

To calculate this, you need the [attenuation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuation_coefficient) $\mu$ of ozone at that light frequency. This describes the spatial attenuation of the intensity $I$ of a light beam $$I=I_0 \exp (-\mu x)$$ The number of photons per unit time and area is proportional to the intensity.

Absorption data on ozone in the pertinent UV wavelength region can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120617123007/http://yly-mac.gps.caltech.edu/N2O/Prasad/Matsumi_O3_cr0205255%20copy.pdf).

Comment: The problem with just using the (total) attenuation coefficient is that a beam of light can be attenuated by either being absorbed or being scattered or both, and the OP's question is focussed on not both of these processes but only absorption. Don't know if it can be assumed that attenuation due to scattering is negligible compared to attenuation due to absorption for ozone at 255 nm.

Comment: @SamuelWeir - Yes you are right, the attenuation coefficient describes the attenuation due to all processes. If you know the absorption probability of ozone at this wavelength, you could slso define an attenuation coefficient for absorption alone.

Comment: In doing a quick google I do see references to the "absorption coefficient" of ozone, so perhaps just saying the "absorption coefficient" of ozone instead of the (total) "attenuation coefficient" of ozone would work.

Comment: @SamuelWeir - Yes, that way you can at least get a lower limit for the attenuation coefficient.